# Difference between terminal and terminator

Tags: command-line

'who am i' when used on terminal displays nothing but not terminator
please explain
screenshots uploaded[image: Terminal Screenshot]

[image: Terminator Screenshot]

Comment: @Terrance I *think* the question is why one of them apparently writes an entry to the `utmp` log and the other doesn't... possibly related [Bug 747046 - cleanup pty.c](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046)

Comment: You are correct, and yes it is a bug in gnome-terminal that will not be fixed.

Comment: u mean there is nothing difference and it is only due to a bug in gnome-terminal??

Comment: I tried filing a bug for `gnome-terminal` not running `whoami` or `who am i` and that is where I found out that they are not going to fix the `gnome-terminal` not showing those commands.  However, from my understanding if you install `screen` or `byobu` and run those in the `gnome-terminal`, `whoami`, `w` and `who am i` all work fine.  The bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1747198

Comment: In gnome-terminal 3.22.1, `who am i` works

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `who -m` (or equivalently `who am i`) does not work in gnome-terminal is due to a bug (or some would say a feature) in gnome-terminal. Specifically, gnome-terminal fails to write an appropriate entry to `/var/run/utmp`, which is what `/usr/bin/who` looks at. The people in charge of gnome-terminal decided, perhaps for good reasons or bad ones, not to support this feature any more. See their discussion here: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046